# How to force the redirection to a new window or tab in a mobile phone browser?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, redirect, mobile, axios

I am developing a "Vue" application which is basically an order form.
In the final step, if you choose to pay directly you are redirected to a secure payment page, opening a new tab in the browser.

```
      const url = "/api/es/orders/" + this.functionalId
      globalAxios
        .put(url, payload, config)
        .then(res => {
          if (res.data.dev_code) {
            if (this.selectedResume === "payment") {
              const urlPayment = Config.PAYMENT_URL + res.data.dev_code
              window.open(urlPayment, "_blank")
            }
          }
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

The problem is that it does this on all devices except mobile phones.
Is there any reason not to do it on mobile?
Should I include something specific?
What am I doing wrong?

thank you all for your time and help

Comment: `Avoid resorting to window.open()` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: @Estradiaz And what would be the other option?

Comment: why do you need a new tab/ window in the first place? cant you just navigate? or embed?

Comment: @javascript110899 Have you tried `<router-link :to="{ name: 'routeName'}" target="_blank">Link</router-link>`? As far as I tested, it works on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/) for this. Look at the [programmatic navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html) segment in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

use `location.href = URL` That's what I do. Theres also `<a href=url>Here</a>` but then they'd need to tap/click it...